# Moving controls to another groupbox during runtime in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two groupboxes. GroupBox1 and GroupBox2. Is it possible to move controls inside `GroupBox1` to `GroupBox2` during runtime ?

For example in the following `xaml` file if I want to move the `label1` in `GroupBox1` to `GroupBox2` during run time. How should I do it ?

```
<Grid>
    <GroupBox Name="GroupBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="MyContent" x:Name="label1"  FontSize="16"/>
                        <Image Name="ImageName1"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="62" Height="42"/>
                </StackPanel>
    </Groupbox>
    <GroupBox Name="GroupBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="MyContent" x:Name="label2" />
                        <Image Name="ImageName2"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="62" Height="42"/>
                </StackPanel>
    </Groupbox>

</Grid>
```

**Note :**
 I do know that I can transform the position of controls during run time by changing their margin value like this:

```
test.Margin = new Thickness(0, -5, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Couldn't you simply duplicate those Controls, and use the Visibility property ?

Comment: I would define two different `DataTemplates` and let a `TemplateSelector` switch between templates for me.

Comment: @Joseph That was my plan B actually I have lot of controls that needs to be moved and one of my controls include data grid as well which will be updated at different conditions. If I duplicate it I need to update data in both the grids.

Comment: @user3596113 I am a newbie in wpf. Dont know much about `DataTemplates`. Will explore it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove it from one `StackPanel` and put into another.

```
stackpanel1.Children.RemoveAt(stackpanel1.Children.IndexOf(label1));
stackpanel2.Children.Add(label1);
```

Comment: Simpler `stackpanel1.Children.Remove(label1);`